# System.Web.HttpContext.Current.get returned null

Tags: c#, browser

i wanna make a C# which scan for opened active tab's URL in the browser.

But when i click the button i got `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.get returned null.`

What could be the problem? Heres my code for button:

```
using System.Web;
[...]
  private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
                if (url == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    label1.Text = url;
                }
                
            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                label1.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: "which scan for opened active tab's URL in the browser." <-- what do you mean by this?

Comment: What, exactly, is `Button1`? Is that a WinForms button, a WebForms button, a WPF button, or something else?

Comment: For example when i open `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71367720/system-web-httpcontext-current-get-returned-null?` the url variable should be the exact browser URL and WinForms button.

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl` is for _server-side_ code. Not client-side HTTP activity. And the WinForms web-browser control does not expose its internal HTTP client API.

Comment: then how should i check the active url in Client-Side?

Comment: What's the `Name` of your WinForms WebBrowser control?

Comment: i dont wanna use implemented WebBrowser, i wanna check the Chrome or Opera, (i mean the default browser) active tab's URL

Comment: That isn't really feasible...

Comment: @Dai what would you do in this situation? what is the way forward in this case?